# How to evaluate solid angle subtended by a segmented circle?

Tags: circles, solid-geometry, solid-angle

[image: segmented circle]

The diagram above shows a circular plane, centered at the origin 'O', has a radius $7 cm$. Two identical rectangular strips, each having width $2 cm$, are thoroughly cut off from the circular plane along x & y axes. Thus four identical segments of the circular plane are left over.

Question: How to calculate the solid angle subtended by the remaining plane (consisting of four identical segments) at a point $P (0, 0, 4cm)$ lying on the z-axis (normally outwards to the plane of paper)?

Solid angle $(\omega)$ subtended by the circular plane, with a radius $r$ at any point lying on the geometrical axis at a distance $h$ from the center, is given as $$\omega=2\pi \left(1-\frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2+r^2}}\right)$$ 
And the solid angle $(\omega)$ subtended by any rectangle of size $l*b$ at any point lying on the perpendicular axis at a distance $d$ from the center is given by standard formula as 
$$\omega=4sin^{-1}\left(\frac{lb}{\sqrt{(l^2+4d^2)(b^2+4d^2)}}\right)$$

But how to apply these formula on the non radial segments of a circle? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The distance d=4 cm, radius R=7cm and gap g=2cm give a solid angle of 1.70538588 if we use my formula in [Solid angle of a Rectangular Plate](https://vixra.org/abs/2001.0603).

Comment: The solution seems to be very lengthy, don't you have any shortcut method to deal with such problems?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.